# my c program to print student details is not working

Tags: c

i build this simple c program that print details of the students . but for some odd reason the program is not working I really don't know how to fix this i've been trying to figure it out for a very long time.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   
   char name[20], section[20], department[20];
   
   int regi_number, phone_number;
  
   
   printf("enter your name: ");
   scanf(" %s", name);
   
    printf("enter your section: ");
   scanf(" %s", section);

    printf("enter your department: ");
   scanf(" %s", department);
   
    printf("enter your register number: ");
   scanf(" %d", regi_number);
   
    printf("enter your phone number: ");
   scanf(" %d", phone_number);
   
   
   printf("your name is %s", name);
   
   printf("your section is %s", section);
   
   printf("your department name is %s", department);
   
   printf("your register number is %d", regi_number);
   
   printf("your phone number is %d" phone_number);
   
   
   
}
```

Comment: `scanf(" %d", &regi_number);` (same `&` for `phone_number`) -- and remember, you cannot use any input function correctly unless you ***check the return*** and validate the input succeeded BEFORE you access the values filled by the input. E.g. `if (scanf(" %d", &regi_number) != 1) { fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr); return 1 }` (note: there is no need for the `' '` before `"%d"` or `"%s"` -- both conversion specifiers discard leading whitespace...) But you DO need a *field-width* modifer with `"%19s"` to protect your array bounds.

Comment: Compile your program with the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` to get all warnings and debug info. Once you get no warnings, use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your executable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to `scanf` a number, you need to put `&` symbol before your variable name.
Also, you forgot `,` in your `printf("your phone number is %d" phone_number);` line.

Here is the corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   
   char name[20], section[20], department[20];
   
   int regi_number, phone_number;
  
   
   printf("enter your name: ");
   scanf(" %s", name);
   
    printf("enter your section: ");
   scanf(" %s", section);

    printf("enter your department: ");
   scanf(" %s", department);
   
    printf("enter your register number: ");
   scanf(" %d", &regi_number);
   
    printf("enter your phone number: ");
   scanf(" %d", &phone_number);
   
   
   printf("your name is %s", name);
   
   printf("your section is %s", section);
   
   printf("your department name is %s", department);
   
   printf("your register number is %d", regi_number);
   
   printf("your phone number is %d", phone_number);
}
```

Here is [a bit](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-input-output) about scanf and numbers:

> You must put **&** in front of the variable used in **scanf**. The reason why will become clear once you learn about **pointers**. It is easy to forget the **&** sign, and when you forget it your program will almost always crash when you run it.

Comment: I would also add a semicolon, space, or new line after each instance of %s and %d so that the information is easier to read and looks neater.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my comment, and in addition to the good answer by [@Beki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13839129/beki), there are a number of additional issues you should address, and some you can optionally address.

The most important of all, is you cannot use any input function correctly, unless you ***Check The Return*** to determine whether the input succeeded or failed -- BEFORE -- you attempt to access the values stored in the variables filled by the input function. Otherwise, you invite *Undefined Behavior*. With `scanf()` (not recommended for user-input), you would use:

```c
printf ("enter your register number: ");
if (scanf ("%d", &regi_number) != 1) {                   /* validate EVERY input */
    fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);   /* handle any error */
    return 1;
}
```

When taking string input with `scanf()` (again, not recommended), you must use the *field-width* modifier to protect your array bound, otherwise `scanf()` is no safer than `gets()` -- See: [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/3422102)

```c
if (scanf ("19%s", name) != 1) {                       /* field-width protects array bounds */
    /* handle cancellation of input */
}
```

(**note:** the space in `" %d"` and `" %s"` is superfluous as both conversion specifiers discard leading whitespace. The only conversion specifiers that DO NOT discard leading whitespace are `"%c"`, `"%[..]"` and `"%n"`)

**Use `fgets()` For ALL User-Input**

To avoid the many `scanf()` pitfalls that trap all new C programmers, you are encouraged to use `fgets()` for all user-input, use `strcspn()` to trim the `'\n'` included by `fgets()` in the buffer, and if a conversion is needed use `sscanf()` to extract the needed information. The following example incorporates all suggestions and removes your reliance on *Magic-Numbers* by declaring a proper constant to use:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 20         /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {
   
    char name[MAXC], section[MAXC], department[MAXC],
        buffer[MAXC];       /* additional array to use as a buffer for integer inputs */
    int regi_number, phone_number;
    
    fputs ("enter your name: ", stdout);            /* no conversion, fputs() is fine */
    if (fgets (name, MAXC, stdin) == NULL) {        /* read all input with fgets() */
        puts ("(user canceled input)");
        return 0;                                   /* cancelation is not an error */
    }
    name[strcspn (name, "\n")] = 0;                 /* trim \n from end of name */
    
    fputs ("enter your section: ", stdout);
    if (!fgets (section, MAXC, stdin)) {            /* read all input with fgets() */
        puts ("(user canceled input)");
        return 0;
    }
    section[strcspn (section, "\n")] = 0;           /* trim \n from end of name */
    
    fputs ("enter your department: ", stdout);
    if (!fgets (department, MAXC, stdin)) {         /* read all input with fgets() */
        puts ("(user canceled input)");
        return 0;
    }
    department[strcspn (department, "\n")] = 0;     /* trim \n from end of name */
    
    fputs ("enter your register number: ", stdout);
    if (!fgets (buffer, MAXC, stdin)) {             /* read all input with fgets() */
        puts ("(user canceled input)");
        return 0;
    }
    if (sscanf (buffer, "%d", &regi_number) != 1) { /* use sscanf to parse value */
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;                                   /* invalid input is an error */
    }
    
    fputs ("enter your phone number: ", stdout);
    if (!fgets (buffer, MAXC, stdin)) {             /* read all input with fgets() */
        puts ("(user canceled input)");
        return 0;
    }
    if (sscanf (buffer, "%d", &phone_number) != 1) {/* use sscanf to parse value */
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    printf ("\nyour name is            : %s\n"
            "your section is         : %s\n"
            "your department name is : %s\n"
            "your register number is : %d\n"
            "your phone number is    : %d\n",
            name, section, department, regi_number, phone_number);
}
```

(**note:** only a single call to `printf()` is necessary)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/input_name_sect_dept
enter your name: Mickey Mouse
enter your section: Toons
enter your department: Toontown
enter your register number: 12345
enter your phone number: 5551212

your name is            : Mickey Mouse
your section is         : Toons
your department name is : Toontown
your register number is : 12345
your phone number is    : 5551212
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Great answer. I myself struggled with `scanf`, and it was you @David C. Rankin who really helped me. Bless you my man!

Comment: Oh it's a small world. Glad it helped. Great answer above. That's what this community is all about -- giving back to those coming up behind you. Keep fighting the good fight.